# iPad : Problem after dismissing Split screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app, I am using split screen for my one view.

but when I use to dismiss that view it gives me screen as below.

[image]

The white portion at right side is because of split screen.

How do I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a reference to that left view, can you change the frame position after dismissing the right view?

Something like:

```
[leftView setFrame:CGRectMake(newX, 0, oldWidth, oldHeight)];
```

Comment: but the screen above does not contain split screen.